# Extract text with gsub

Tags: r, text

I am setting up an automated data analysis procedure and, more or less at the end of the procedure, I would like to extract automatically the name of the file that has been analysed. I have a data frame with a column containing names, with the following style:

- Baseline/Cell_Line_2_**KB_1813_B**_Baseline
- Dose 0001/Cell_Line_3_**KB1720_1**_0001
- Dose 0010/Cell_Line_1_**KB1810 mat**_0010

I would like to extract just the characters in bold: "KB_1813_B", "KB1720_1" and "KB1810 mat" in a separate column.

I used gsub with the following command:

```
df$column.with.names <- gsub(".*KB|_.*", "KB", df$column.with.new.names)
```

I could easily remove the first part of the problem, but I am stuck trying to remove the second part. Is there some command in gsub to remove everything, starting from the end of the name, until you encounter a special character ( "_" in my case)?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(df$column.with.new.names, "KB_*\\d+[_ ]*[^_]*")
#[1] "KB_1813_B"  "KB1720_1"   "KB1810 mat"
```

---

Or the same pattern can be captured as a group with `sub`

```
sub(".*(KB_*\\d+[_ ]*[^_]*).*", "\\1", df$column.with.new.names)
#[1] "KB_1813_B"  "KB1720_1"   "KB1810 mat"
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(column.with.new.names = c("Baseline/Cell_Line_2_KB_1813_B_Baseline", 
 "Dose 0001/Cell_Line_3_KB1720_1_0001",
  "Dose 0010/Cell_Line_1_KB1810 mat_0010"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. With this code I could solve 95% of the problems, but two types of names were not extracted. Two examples: KB1820_Baseline, of which I would like to extract only KB1820_ and KB1890_0002, of which I would like to extract just KB1890_

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is using regex groups:

```
x <- c("Baseline/Cell_Line_2_KB_1813_B_Baseline",
"Dose 0001/Cell_Line_3_KB1720_1_0001",
"Dose 0010/Cell_Line_1_KB1810 mat_0010")

gsub("^.+Cell_Line_._(.+)_.+$", "\\1", x)
[1] "KB_1813_B"  "KB1720_1"   "KB1810 mat"
```